# SQL TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP: How to remove miliseconds?

Tags: python, html, sql, postgresql

**Problem:** When I print time in my HTML code it shows like this: 2020-05-31 03:29:50.617897

**Code:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTIXy.png

**Question:** How to get rid of decimal .617897? Thank you. I'm new to programming.

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "[python] round time to seconds" or "[python] format time string" or "[python] format time (in that framework your are using that accepts {{ time }} in HTML)".

Comment: There probably is not much of a reason to drag SQL into this, unless explicitly wishing to do the operation before the result is returned to Python; in part, this is because one still might want to control the output formatting anyway.

Comment: I searched for it but i still cant get a hold of it. :( im using jinja as for my framework btw.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4830535/2864740 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/12681036/2864740 via "python jinja format time"; and [formatting for strfime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) via "python strftime".

Comment: So be welcome! Please note that per SO rules, your question should include all the relevant code, **as text**. It would make it really better and would avoid downvotes/closure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Postgres, you can use `date_trunc()`:

```
select date_trunc('second', current_timestamp)
```

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
a = '2020-05-31 03:29:50.617897'
a = a.split('.')[0]
print(a)
```

Output:

```
'2020-05-31 03:29:50'
```