# Python rounding error with simple sum

Tags: python, rounding, precision

```
>>> sum([0.3, 0.1, 0.2])
0.6000000000000001

>>> sum([0.3, 0.1, 0.2]) == 0.6
False
```

What can I do to make the result be exactly 0.6? 
I don't want to round the result to a certain number of decimal digits because then I could lose precision for other list instances.

Comment: Why do you need exactly 0.6? Would you have the same problem if `1.0/3+2.0/3` did not exactly equal `1`?

Comment: I want exactly 0.6 because that is the result I'd expect. Yes, it, would be the same problem.

Comment: There are plenty of posts on this on SO already, e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python

Comment: @user2460978 I'm afraid the answer is to adjust your expectations. There isn't a good general-purpose way to have math with rationals work as you'd expect while still permitting things like square roots and sines.

Comment: Welcome to floating point. 0.6 cannot be exactly represented in binary floating point.

Comment: but 0.6 + 0 returns 0.6

Comment: @user2460978 When you write `0.6`, this is turned into a base 2 *approximation* of the rational number 6/10. Adding zero to it doesn't change that number. Then you print said approximation, and Python conveniently (or confusingly, depending on your point of view) hides the approximation by rounding it into 0.6 which, if put back into Python code, would *again* turn into the same approximation of 6/10. At no point Python actually stored the real number 0.6 or the rational 6/10.

Comment: @delnan well, my question is exactly why it 'hides', as you say, the approximation in the case 0.6+0 but not in the case 0.1+0.2+0.3

Comment: @user2460978 The value resulting from evaluating `0.60+` (or `0.6` because +0 doesn't change anything) can be reproduced by parsing the string `"0.6"`. The value resulting from evaluating `0.1+0.2+0.3` cannot be reproduced by parsing `0.6`, because the compound rounding errors in parsing "0.1", "0.2", "0.3" and adding them is different from (and larger than) the rounding error in parsing "0.6". See http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ for exploring this interactively. Perhaps "hide" is the wrong term, is seeks the shortest decimal string that reproduces the bits stored when parsed.

Comment: A more general canonical question: *[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)*. 2009. 85 answers (incl. deleted). 4000 upvotes. 1/2 million views. [5,015 linked questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/588004?sort=votes)(!), presumably most of them duplicates.

Comment: Some more Python ones: *[How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/)*, *[Why does the floating-point value of 4*0.1 look nice in Python 3 but 3*0.1 doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618943/)*, *[Round up to second decimal place in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/)*, and *[Rounding errors in Python floor division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588815)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `float` is inherently imprecise in pretty much every language because it cannot be represented precisely in binary.

If you need exact precision use the `Decimal` `class`:

```
from decimal import Decimal

num1 = Decimal("0.3")
num2 = Decimal("0.2")
num3 = Decimal("0.1")

print(sum([num1, num2, num3]))
```

Which will `return` the very pleasing result of:

```
Decimal('0.6')  # One can do float() on this output to get plain (0.6).
```

Which conveniently is also a `Decimal` object with which you can work.

Comment: `Decimal` is also a floating point number, just using a different base. It can represent the literals one writes in decimal notation exactly, but in turn is less accurate than binary ("ordinary") floats in other cases.

Comment: Interesting. When you say 'using a different base', I assume it's base 10?

Comment: @user2460978 Exactly. Instead of {some integer} * 2^x (that's what a `float` looks like), a `decimal` is stored as {some integer} * 10^x.

Answer (score -2):

Use `math.fsome()` instead of `sum()`.

Comment: I guess you mean [`math.fsum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) rather than `math.fsome`? (There's no such thing as `math.fsome` in Python.) But even then, it's not really a solution to the problem: try `math.fsum([0.1, 0.2, 0.4])`, for example. On a typical machine, the result won't be equal to `0.7`.