# Python round to nearest .0125

Tags: python, rounding

Does anyone know how to round a number to nearest .0125? For example there's a number 167.1131 then it needs to be converted to 167.1125. I have tried to do it with `round` but it rounds to 0.x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round up to Third decimal Place in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/round-up-to-third-decimal-place-in-python)

Comment: What is the end purpose of the rounding up? This issue, perhaps can be addressed elsewhere along the line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Convert it to "0.0125's", round THAT, and convert back:

```
round(x/0.0125)*0.0125
```

Comment: Hmm, other way round?

Comment: @quamrana: Well, if x=5, the above yields 5, while switching the '*' and '`' (which is what I assume "other way round" means) yields 0.  So, no?

Comment: Ok, my bad. I usually mistake true for false in `if` statements. This time its mistaking `/0.0125` for `/80`!  I would do it like this: `round(x*80)/80`

Comment: @quamrana: Or there's also `0.125 * round(x*8.0, 1)`, which should be correctly rounded (in case that matters, and assuming that overflow and underflow are avoided in the multiplications).

Answer (score 2):

The `round()` function is focused on rounding to tenths, hundredths, thousandths and so on - essentially rounding to some negative exponent of 10.

So, as 0.0125 is not such a number that the `round()` can handle, you can

- either apply a multiplication to your input number before giving it to `round`, so that it can do a rounding for which it is designed, and afterwards you correct for the initial multiplication. One of the other answers does it like this.
- or you can, if you think the first approach looks complicated, solve the problem with pure mathematics. The code below essentially looks how much there is actually "too much" above a multiple of 0.0125. This "too much" amount is a remainder (modulus) of a division. This division is done on integers, so there is an initial multiplication and correction afterwards, just like in the first approach.

Code for the second approach:

```
def round_0125(number):
    mult_number = number * 10000
    remainder = mult_number % 125
    return (mult_number - remainder) / 10000

round_0125(167.1131)
#167.1125

round_0125(167.5738)
#167.5625
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value = 167.1125
dec_value = value % 1     # get decimal part
whole_value = value // 1
my_range = np.arange(0, 1, 0.0125)

distance = np.abs(dec_value - my_range)   # get the absolute distance
index = np.argmin(distance)   # find the index of smallest distance
result = whole_value + my_range[index]
```

Comment: Did you maybe mean `np.arange` instead of `np.argmin`?