# How to round to nearest decimal in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first time working with Python. I'm trying to figure out how to round decimals in the simplest way possible.

```
print("\nTip Calculator")

costMeal = float(input("Cost of Meal:"))

tipPrct = .20
print("Tip Percent: 20%")

tip = costMeal * tipPrct

print("Tip Amount: " + str(tip))

total = costMeal + tip
print("Total Amount: " + str(total))
```

[I need it to look like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lPkG.png)

Comment: So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/round-up-to-second-decimal-place-in-python/9232295#9232295) isn't helping?

Comment: Have you tried `round(some_value, 1)`?

Comment: There is a function called `round()`, but you could also just use formatting for how you display the number.

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding how to use round() with what I'm doing.. would I put it on it's own like: round(total, 2)? Because when I try that it doesn't do anything to the numbers

Comment: Ah I figured it out! Thank you all for your answers

Comment: @hts95, glad you figured it out. So people in the future can get a good answer, make sure you accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You should use [Python's built-in round function.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-function-python/)**

**Syntax of round():**

```
round(number, number of digits)
```

**Parameters of round():**

```
..1) number - number to be rounded
..2) number of digits (Optional) - number of digits 
     up to which the given number is to be rounded.
     If not provided, will round to integer.
```

**Therefore, you should try code more like:**

```
print("\nTip Calculator")

costMeal = float(input("Cost of Meal: "))

tipPrct = .20
print("Tip Percent: 20%")

tip = costMeal * tipPrct
tip = round(tip, 2) ## new line

print("Tip Amount: " + str(tip))

total = costMeal + tip
print("Total Amount: " + str(total))
```