# How to round 0.055 to 0.06 in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Result of a simple division `-34.11/2` returns `-17.055` Is there a python function that would return round up decimal? I am expecting to see `-17.06`

And yes I checked these answers, but neither can answer this question:
[Round up to Second Decimal Place in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/round-up-to-second-decimal-place-in-python)

[How to round to nearest decimal in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57011481/how-to-round-to-nearest-decimal-in-python)

[Increment a Python floating point value by the smallest possible amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063755/increment-a-python-floating-point-value-by-the-smallest-possible-amount)
[Python round to nearest 0.25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257635/python-round-to-nearest-0-25)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `import numpy as np` `np.round(0.05, 2)`

Comment: This is, actually, answered by the questions you linked to. Please read the documentation on [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a floating point limitation; get around it by using `decimal.Decimal`.

```py
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal(-34.11/2)  # See? Not quite the value you thought.
Decimal('-17.05499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875')
>>> Decimal(-34.11) / Decimal(2)  # This doesn't quite work either, because -34.11 is already a little bit off.
Decimal('-17.05499999999999971578290570')
>>> Decimal("-34.11") / Decimal("2")
Decimal('-17.055')
>>> round(Decimal("-34.11") / Decimal("2"), 2)
Decimal('-17.06')
```

Comment: The output from `round(Decimal("-34.11") / Decimal("2"), 2)` will be `'decimal.Decimal'` object. So for further calculation we need to convert it to float object right?.

Comment: @mohammedwazeem Yes—something as simple as `float(result)`. But. If you care about the rounding of your real numbers, you probably shouldn't be using floats anyway.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy yes, nice solution.