# Rounding two similar numbers and getting different results Python

Tags: python, rounding

I am trying to compare two different values in Python: **59.725** and **59.72497**.

I am rounding them both using the Python round function as doing `df.round(2)` doesn't work how I need it to:

```
def round_df_columns(df, col_list):
        for col_name in col_list:
            for x in df[col_name]:
                rounded_x = round(x, 2)
                df[col_name] = df[col_name].replace(x, rounded_x)
        return df
```

However, when I do this I get **59.73** and **59.72**. Is there a way of rounding these values so that they both round up to 59.73? I couldn't find a similar question, but sorry if this is a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Post your code. We need to reproduce your problem.

Comment: thats not how rounding works

Comment: That's...correct rounding by Python? Below 5 and round down, 5 and above round up. If you're desperate to round *everything* up, you could just `round(x+0.005, 2)`.

Comment: You could multiply both numbers by 100, use the ceiling function (math.ceil), and then divide them by 100 again. But the behaviour you've seen from the rounding is mathematically correct - 59.72497 is less than 59.725 (i.e. less than halfway to 59.73) so should round to 59.72

Comment: As LowIntHighCha suggests: [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9232310/7891382)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution is using `math.ceil`.

Try

```
import math

x = math.ceil(100 * 59.72497) / 100
print(x)

y = math.ceil(100 * 59.725) / 100
print(y)
```

Ouput

```
59.73
59.73
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to always round up, add 0.005 to the value before you round.  E.g.

```
rounded_x = round(x + 0.005, 2)
```